# Python Request Module throws 403 Error + SharePoint Online

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, python-requests, sharepoint-online, digest-authentication

I am currently writing a script which will pull information from sharepoint online. To do this outside the sharepoint environment. I need to get the token and Cookies (FedAuth, rtFa). Sames cookies i can get using the requests in python.

Now, If i pass the same cookies in header in my script, while fetching the List data from SP Online. it throws 403 Error. But if same cookies i use in Postman to fetch the list data. It successfully fetches the information.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

EDIT: figured out the answer, [here is the link for the same](https://github.com/parthrawal/Python.O365/blob/master/SharePointOnline.py)

Comment: Could you consider showcasing your code?

Comment: Thanks, Sorry new to this This code is after fetching the Cookies and when i try to get the information from SharePoint online. I receive this error. This i could resolve by putting ; in between 2 cookies (FedAuth and rtFa) and

Comment: Now i am getting another error from sahrepoint that Max retry reached. `'url=TopLevelUrl+"""sites/dev/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('{}')/Items?$top=1"""
    url=url.format('RRF')
    print(url)

    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    _Fedauth='FedAuth={}'.format(response.cookies['FedAuth'])
    _rtFa='rtFa={}'.format(response.cookies['rtFa'])
    _FinalDict={'Cookie':_Fedauth+';'+_rtFa}

    headers.update(_FinalDict)

    response=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    print (response.content)`

Comment: Could you consider showcasing your code? Your question does not meet the terms for a good question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: refer this link https://github.com/parthrawal/Python.O365/blob/master/SharePointOnline.py